# Avoid case change when writing to CSV file using java program

Tags: csv, java-8, opencsv

I have a below java program which reads data from an input file and write data to
a output file ( I am using OpenCSV)

```
 FileReader filereader = new FileReader("C:\\InputFile.csv");
 CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader).withSkipLines(1).build();

 FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter("C:\\OutputFile.csv");
 CSVWriter writer =  new CSVWriter(outputfile, ',',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.RFC4180_LINE_END);

 String[] header = { "ID", "IDRange", "Param1", "Param2", "PresentOrNot" };
 writer.writeNext(header);
 
 List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
 List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

 for (String[] row : allData) 
 {
     data.add(new String[] {String.valueOf("1", "35", row[4], row[5],"True" });
 }
 writer.writeAll(data);
 writer.close();
```

This is the issue i want to resolve:

**Question** : When I see the data in OutputFile.csv , "True" which is camel case in java program is written as TRUE, how to make sure it is written in same case(lower, camel etc) as the java program ? .

Comment: Can someone please help with this issue ? -/\-

Answer (score 0):

I could see your code is working fine. If you open csv with Excel, it will show 'True' as 'TRUE'. Try opening the file in Notepad or some other Text editor. You will see value as 'True' only.

This is output your code generated and displayed in Notepad++ as:

#ID,IDRange,Param1,Param2,PresentOrNot#
1,35,2,1,True

**Its Excel causing the behaviour not your code.